# .Switchable graphics AMD 6770M and intel hd graphics

Tags: windows-8

I have installed latest beta drivers of AMD 6770M on my windows 8.My laptop is also having a on board low performane Intel graphic card.The laptop offers feature called **switchable graphics** which allows you to select the low performance or high performane amd graphic card manually.However after upgrading to windows 8 and installing the drivers the switchable graphics feature is not being supported.How can I resolve the above issue?

Comment: What are switchable graphics?

Comment: hybrid graphics like nvidia optimus

Comment: Is your on-processor graphics from the HD4000 or older generation? If so, it likely doesn't work on Windows 8 because AMD stopped supporting HD4000 era graphics.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his card is still supported by AMD...

Comment: The 6770 is, but some systems sell with Radeon 4000 series on the CPU die (APU) and 6000 series on the discrete. The 4000 series in this case would be unsupported.

Comment: Please edit this to make it a question.

Comment: Seems like you have posted answer in the question itself.

Comment: yes i have added the answer later.

Comment: If you have found a solution then you should post it as answer and accept it to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**I have just installed unified drivers provided by leshcatlabs.net.The drivers are working pretty good.Now my windows 8 pc is showing options for switchable graphics.To install the drivers just follow the following steps.
1.Uninstall all the AMD and Intel drivers by selecting device manager from control panel.

2.Download the latest leshlabs drivers from http://leshcatlabs.net/

3.Follow the steps mentioned in their manaul.

4.Reboot

Voila!The system will with switchable graphics options.

[image: switchable graphics]

Comment: I would not download a driver that isn't direct from the manufacturer..

Comment: yes you are right but this was the only solution I found.Yes I am looking for drivers for windows 8 from my vendor.

Comment: AMD has them on their site.

Comment: However, when I click `Configure Switchable Graphics` nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest Catalyst for your GPU?
[64 bit driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx)
[32 bit driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-32.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

AMD driver download page states that drivers downloaded from it, the generic drives, may be incompatible with switchable graphics. You you should get the drivers from the laptop manufacture's site.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.eightforums.com/graphic-cards/7088-win-8-amd-switchable-graphics-faq-intel-amd-3000-6770m-owner.html) a thread addressing the problem, solutions include instaling Windows 7 drivers using Windows 8 Compatibility Mode, installing third party drivers such as [leshcat](http://leshcatlabs.net/) or forcing one the cards on/off in the BIOS(but you seem to want both working).